# How to mock a custom hook when rendering a component in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mocking, react-testing-library

I've searched all over looking for an answer to this but I can't seem to find one. But apologies if I am repeating a question from somewhere else.

I am currently testing a component that uses a custom hook I wrote for retrieving data from a Firestore database. The custom hook provides and array of objects, which is then used by array.map within the component to render information onto the screen. To keep things simple I created a simple component <MyComponent />. The component uses a returned array of objects from the custom hook and renders it to a list.

I have written a test that mocks the custom hook to return an array of objects. The test then expects a specific string to be present in the document. But the test fails as it cannot find the string. I'm unsure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the simple component that is is rendering the data returned by the custom hook
I haven't included the custom hook (useCollection) as its being mocked and the test doesn't care about how the hook is implemented.

```
import React from "react";
import useCollection from "../CustomHooks/UseCollection";

export default function MyComponent() {
  const { collectionData } = useCollection('Location', null);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{collectionData.map((item) => (<li key={item.id}>{item.id}</li>))}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the test i have written to mock the custom hook data, render the component and expect the string value "Belfast".

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import useCollection from '../CustomHooks/UseCollection';

it('render my component', () => {
    screen.debug()
    const mockUseCollection = jest.fn(() => ({
        collectionData: [{id:"Belfast"},{id:"Derry"}],
    }));

    jest.mock('../CustomHooks/UseCollection', () => ({
        useCollection: mockUseCollection,
    }));

    const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent />);
    expect(getByText("Belfast")).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

when the test runs I get the error 'TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Belfast.'

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move mockUseCollection & jest.mock out of the test and then use the following in your test: const mockData = { /* desired mock data */ };
  useCollection.mockReturnValue(mockData);

Comment: thanks @jackwaayer that worked. My real component uses multiple instances of the useCollection hook. Each instance of the hook returns data which I rename as locationData and CenterData repsectively. This information gets passed through array.map for rendering. Is there a way to modify the code to deal with 2 hook instances?

Answer (score 0):

To mock multiple implementations of the same hook, you could try something like this

```js
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import useCollection from '../CustomHooks/UseCollection';

jest.mock('../CustomHooks/UseCollection');

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should render correctly with mocked hooks', () => {
    // mock the first implementation of useMyHook
    useCollection.mockReturnValueOnce('output 1');

    // test the component with the first implementation of useMyHook
    // ...

    // mock the second implementation of useMyHook
    useCollection.mockReturnValueOnce('output 2');

    // test the component with the second implementation of useMyHook
    // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: mockReturnValueOnce is not a method of an imported custom hook